# Delete multiple lines from multiple files using sed

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep, command

I am trying do delete some line that match following regex using sed.

Command to get all lines from all files which are to be deleted

```
grep  -P '.*Society[ \t]*([0-9]*[ \t]*[0-9]*)[ \t]*bhavan$' *.ann
```

Results:

```
file0122.ann:T324   Society 4520 4526   bhavan
file0126.ann:T225   Society 9191 9197   bhavan
file0319.ann:T84    Society 43 49   bhavan
file0376.ann:T65    Society 2611 2617   bhavan
file0627.ann:T171   Society 4104 4110   bhavan
file1159.ann:T87    Society 4073 4079   bhavan
file1533.ann:T150   Society 2787 2793   bhavan
file1582.ann:T80    Society 2548 2554   bhavan
file1813.ann:T115   Society 1213 1219   bhavan
file1876.ann:T163   Society 1998 2004   bhavan
file1879.ann:T165   Society 2513 2519   bhavan
file2521.ann:T109   Society 326 332 bhavan
file2537.ann:T100   Society 2574 2580   bhavan
file3725.ann:T109   Society 2988 2994   bhavan
```

I am using following sed command to delete above lines from all files

`sed -i -e '/.*Society[ \t]*([0-9]*[ \t]*[0-9]*)[ \t]*bhavan$/d' *.ann`

But it doing nothing. Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by changing small e to E which includs  --regexp-extended regex in sed.

```
sed -i -E '/.*Society[ \t]*([0-9]*[ \t]*[0-9]*)[ \t]*bhavan$/d' *.ann
```

Comment: And why do you need to enable EREs? Answer: Because you have unnecessary parens in your regexp.

Comment: Okay. Right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the `-v` switch to `grep`. This will invert the logic, i.e. only select lines not matching the pattern.

From `grep.info`:

```
‘-v’
‘--invert-match’
     Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (‘-v’
     is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `(` and `)` from the regexp as they aren't present in your input. You're telling grep to use a PCRE (`-P`) where those parens represent a capture group (which you aren't using and so they are redundant) but then calling sed without any RE-specific options so it's using a BRE where those parens are literal characters. The `.*` at the start of your regexp is doing nothing useful, btw, so you could just remove that too.